# Compare rows and columns of same table

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

```
+--------------+--------------+------------+
| company_name | address_type |  address   |
+--------------+--------------+------------+
| Company A    | Billing      | 111 Street |
| Company A    | Shipping     | 111 Street |
| Company B    | Billing      | 222 Street |
| Company B    | Shipping     | 333 street |
| Company B    | Shipping     | 444 street |
+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

I have a table similar to this.
What i need is **All the companies whose billing address and shipping address are different**.

NOTE - Each company has only ONE billing address. But it can have multiple Shipping addresses

This seems like a fairly simple query but I'm not just able to get it.

My attempt - I tried 'subtracting' all the shipping address from Billing but there's just no output. 
Distinct doesn't help as well

Query:

```
select company_name 
from tableA 
where address_type='Billing' 
and company_name not in (select to_char(company_name) from tableA where address_type='Shipping');
```

Output should be **Company B** (since it's billing and shipping address is different)

EDIT 1 : Tried Indra's query but it runs forever. No response

```
select A.* from company A inner join company B on A.company_Name = B.company_Name
and (A.address_type = 'Billing' and B.address_type = 'Shipping') 
AND A.address <> B.address
```

Comment: `My attempt` show that ..

Comment: select company_name from tableA where address_type='Billing' and company_name not in (select to_char(company_name) from tableA where address_type='Shipping');

Comment: What dbms are you using? ORACLE? MySQL? SQL Server?...

Answer (score 1):

How about using a `join`?  The following shows all pairs that are different:

```
select tb.*, ts.*
from company tb join
     company ts
     on tb.company_name = ts.company_name and
        ts.address_type = 'shipping' and
        tb.address_type = 'billing' and
        ts.address <> tb.address;
```

If you just want the companies that are different:

```
select company_name
from company t
group by company_name
having count(distinct case when t.address_type = 'billing' then address end) = 1 and
       count(distinct case when t.address_type = 'shipping' then address end) = 1 and
       (max(case when t.address_type = 'billing' then address end) <>
        max(case when t.address_type = 'shipping' then address end)
       );
```

Note:  this also checks that there is only one distinct billing and shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Query

```
select A.* from company A inner join company B on A.company_Name = B.company_Name
and (A.address_type = 'Billing' and B.address_type = 'Shipping') 
AND A.address <> B.address
```

Comment: There are around million rows and there are not just two companies. There are several companies. Also it's just one table

Comment: @user155581 please update your question accordingly.... And why this will not work for you.

Comment: The query runs into an infinite loop. ( Execution time is over 5 minutes now , yet no response.) Usual response time is few miliseconds

Comment: @user155581, you can use this query as well `select distinct c.company_name from comp C where address_type = 'Billing' and not exists( select 1 from comp  where c.company_Name = company_Name and address_type = 'Shipping' and c.address <>address )`

Answer (score 0):

In this [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91e929/5), you can find other approach with one more company:

```
+--------------+--------------+------------+
| company_name | address_type |  address   |
+--------------+--------------+------------+
| Company A    | Billing      | 111 Street |
| Company A    | Shipping     | 111 Street |
| Company B    | Billing      | 222 Street |
| Company B    | Shipping     | 333 street |
| Company B    | Shipping     | 444 street |
| Company C    | Shipping     | 555 street |
| Company C    | Shipping     | 666 street |
| Company C    | Billing      | 555 street |
| Company C    | Billing      | 666 street |
+--------------+--------------+------------+
```

**POSTDATA**: SQL Fiddle works fine for me. This is all the code:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE companies
( 
  company_name  VARCHAR2(40),
  address_type  VARCHAR2(40),
  address    VARCHAR2(40)
);

insert into companies values ('Company A','Billing','111 Street' );
insert into companies values ('Company A','Shipping','111 Street' );
insert into companies values ('Company B','Billing','222 Street' );
insert into companies values ('Company B','Shipping','333 street' );
insert into companies values ('Company B','Shipping','444 street');
insert into companies values ('Company C','Billing','555 Street' );
insert into companies values ('Company C','Billing','666 Street' );
insert into companies values ('Company C','Shipping','555 Street' );
insert into companies values ('Company C','Shipping','666 Street' );
```

Sentece:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(comp.company_name) FROM
    (select company_name, address, count(*) regs
    from companies
    group by company_name, address) comp
WHERE MOD(comp.regs,2) = 1;
```

Result:

```
Company B
```

Comment: SQL fiddle crashes every time i click on your link. Can you check it once ? (or share the complete code)

Comment: Also, each company has only ONE shipping address. But it can have multiple Shipping addresses

Comment: Then, if shipping address exists into billing address, is a "discardable" company, isn't it?